# Formula to perform an "if" on a grouping of rows in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### BACKGROUND

I have the following table (**Table1**) with some dummy data.

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, GroupId
1, 100, [Set to ColA or ColB value], GroupA
2, 200, [Set to ColA or ColB value], GroupA
3, 300, [Set to ColA or ColB value], GroupA
4, 400, [Set to ColA or ColB value], GroupB
5, 500, [Set to ColA or ColB value], GroupB
```

As you can see, the **GroupId** column is used to logically group rows. I have 2 groupings above: `GroupA` and `GroupB`.

**ColC** is set to either **ColA** or **ColB** depending on various factors. That part is done.

Below **Table1**, I need another table (**Table2**) that tells me if every row within a grouping has `ColA = ColC`.

For example:

```
GroupID, ColAEqColC
GroupA,
GroupB,
```

### PROBLEM

So, logically I want the formula in **ColAEqColC** to be:

`if(For all the rows in Table1 where Table2.GroupId = Table1.GroupId, is ColA = ColC?, "Yes", "No")`

However, I don't know how to get all that into the first parameter of an `if` statement.

### EXAMPLE:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC, GroupId
1, 100, 1, GroupA
2, 200, 2, GroupA
3, 300, 3, GroupA
4, 400, 4, GroupB
5, 500, 500, GroupB
```

```
GroupID, ColAEqColC
GroupA, Yes
GroupB, No
```

Comment: Does your version of Excel support Dynsmic Array functions?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes. I'm using Office 365 and verified it supports Dynamic Arrays. I'll start reading about that option and see if it can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilising the Dynamic Array function `FILTER`:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(Table1[[GroupId]],(Table1[ColA]=Table1[[ColC]])*(Table1[[GroupId]]=[@[GroupId]])))=COUNTIFS(Table1[[GroupId]],[@[GroupId]])
```

Returns `TRUE`/`FALSE`.  Wrap in `IF( ... , "Yes", "No")` if you really want text output

Comment: Works great *and* gives me something to learn from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(SUM((Table1[GroupId]=Table2[@GroupID])*(Table1[ColA]=Table1[ColC]))=COUNTIFS(Table1[GroupId],Table2[@GroupID]),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: good answer.  Here's a slighly simplified version `=SUM((Table1[GroupId]=[@GroupId])*(Table1[ColA]<>Table1[ColC]))=0`

Comment: Thanks. I stared at my formula and thought that there must be a simpler way without the COUNTIFS, but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: I'm not able to upvote, this also taught me a lot. Thanks for the help!